# How to remove a project from VS code that I might have cloned by mistake?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to remove a project from VS code that I might have cloned by mistake?

I'm a newbie. Please explain.

Comment: what does "removing a project" mean?

Comment: is this is what you are looking for [How to remove folders from Visual Studio Code](https://superuser.com/questions/912654/how-to-remove-folders-from-visual-studio-code)

Comment: i cloned this https://github.com/flutter/flutter and i want to remove it.

Comment: If you do not want the repo on your system, simply delete the directory. If you want to keep the repo but don't want it showing up in your *workspace* (that is a VS code term, which might be how you're using "project") then you can right-click the directory in the explorer and click "Remove folder from workspace"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.